# Is there a way to interchange mathematical operators in a while or for loop?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program in C to try out how 6 numbers, that get input by the user (that's no problem so far), are combined in every possible way.

I tried using the search function but I am not quite sure what to look for.

It should do kind of like that:

```c
...
temp[i] = a + b + c + d - e - f;
i++;
temp[i] = a + b + c - d - e - f;
i++;
temp[i] = a + b - c - d - e - f;
i++;
...
```

Also with multiplying and dividing.

It would be nice to also implement all ways of putting in brackets and not using all the numbers.

So like brute forcing all possible results from these numbers.

Is there any way to achieve this without coding in every combination by hand?

Comment: Define functions that perform the mathematical operations. Then you can put them in an array of function pointers, and change the array in a loop.

Comment: Well, 6 nested for loops should do

Comment: I'm not sure about what's the meaning of _"implement all ways of putting in brackets and not using all the numbers"_. Talking about the operators, it would be somewhat feasible using five nested loops, but you should still pay attention to ZeroDivisions. Otherwise you could write a program... that writes your program (with all the permutations you want).

Comment: The answer to your question is: yes, to both the one in the title and the other one in the text. The reason that's probably not a helpful answer is that it's a bad question. Consider reading [ask] again. For a start, reduce the problem (maybe to three variables) and then solve it yourself. That should allow you to see a pattern and to generalize to further variables.

Answer (score 3):

[Recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60197683/1679849) is quite useful for this sort of thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void compute_all_combinations(int *list, int length, int running_total) {
    if (length <= 0) {
        printf("%d\n", running_total);
        return;
    }
    compute_all_combinations(list+1, length-1, running_total + *list);
    compute_all_combinations(list+1, length-1, running_total - *list);
}

int main() {
    int numbers[4] = { 3141, 5926, 5358, 9793 };
    compute_all_combinations(numbers, 4, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

The `compute_all_combinations()` function will accept a list of any length (within reason). It calls itself recursively to span the entire decision tree representing the sums you're trying to compute (i.e., at each node, fork left/right to add/subtract the node's value), and print out the results at each leaf node. I hope it's fairly self-explanatory

Comment: This is in a right direction. It gets tricky when multiplication and division comes in, so it would be better for op to build equation as string and evaluate at base case.

Comment: This is elegant, but OP should be aware that it computes all operations in the form `(((...(a # b) # c) # d) # ... )` where `#` is an operator. It will always compute left-to-right with not regard to precedence.

Comment: Ah, that's true. For addition and subtraction it should work fine though.

Comment: This may use up a lot of stack, although it is a good solution.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Not really; there are only 3 local variables. And with a recursion depth of 40 levels and two branches at each call, that's already over a trillion permutations.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fun little problem on which I've already spent far too much time!  I wouldn't go with recursion for the permutations, but that's not really the challenging part of the question.  Getting the groupings is easy if you use postfix instead of trying to do groupings with infix.  On the assumption that I've made some copy paste errors, this (along with a test suite!) can also be found at https://github.com/wrp/examples/blob/master/c/arithperm.c.  A sample run:

```
$ ./a.out 1.54 3 7.4 -2.3 1 78 | awk 'NR % 4027 == 0'
((1.54 / ((3 * 7.4) * -2.3)) * 1) / 78 = -0.000386674
((1.54 - 3) - ((7.4 - -2.3) / 1)) / 78 = -0.143077
(1.54 + ((3 + 7.4) / (-2.3 + 1))) / 78 = -0.0828205
((1.54 * (3 / 7.4)) * -2.3) * (1 / 78) = -0.0184096
((1.54 * 3) - 7.4) * ((-2.3 * 1) * 78) = 498.732
1.54 * (((3 + (7.4 - -2.3)) * 1) - 78) = -100.562
1.54 * ((3 - (7.4 / (-2.3 + 1))) + 78) = 133.506
1.54 - (((3 / 7.4) - -2.3) / (1 - 78)) = 1.57514
1.54 - (3 * (((7.4 * -2.3) + 1) - 78)) = 283.6
1.54 - (3 - ((7.4 - -2.3) + (1 / 78))) = 8.25282
```

Here's the code that generates the above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct expression {
        double *operands;    /* The numbers to be manipulated */
        char operators[16];  /* operators to apply, eg "++/-*" */
        uint32_t mask;       /* A bit mask showing where to apply operators */
        int count;           /* Number of operands */
        struct element {
                double val;
                char descr[512];  /* Human readable description (for infix) */
        } *stack;                 /* Stack used for computation */
};

void * xmalloc(size_t s);
void parse_cmd_line(int argc, char **argv, struct expression*);
int next_op(struct expression *);
void eval(struct expression *);

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        struct expression exp;

        parse_cmd_line(argc, argv, &exp);
        do eval(&exp); while(next_op(&exp));
        free(exp.operands);
        free(exp.stack);
}


/*
 * Evaluate the expression and pretty print it to stdout
 */
void
eval(struct expression *exp)
{
        int c = 0;
        uint32_t m = exp->mask;
        char *ops = exp->operators;
        struct element *sp = exp->stack;

        while( m ) {
                if( m & 0x1 ) { /* Apply an operator */
                        char buf[1024];
                        char *fmt = (m == 1) ? "%s %c %s" : "(%s %c %s)";
                        assert(sp - exp->stack > 1); /* True because of mask_is_invalid() */
                        assert(sizeof buf >= sizeof sp->descr); /* Ensure terminating null after strncpy */
                        sp -= 2;
                        snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, fmt, sp->descr, *ops, sp[1].descr);
                        strncpy(sp->descr, buf, sizeof sp->descr);
                        switch(*ops++) {
                        case '+': sp->val += sp[1].val; break;
                        case '-': sp->val -= sp[1].val; break;
                        case '*': sp->val *= sp[1].val; break;
                        case '/': sp->val /= sp[1].val; break;
                        default: assert(0);
                        }
                } else {
                        assert(c < exp->count);
                        sp->val = exp->operands[c++];
                        snprintf(sp->descr, sizeof sp->descr, "%g", sp->val);
                }
                sp += 1;
                assert( sp - exp->stack <= exp->count );
                m >>= 1;
        }
        sp -= 1;
        printf("%s = %g\n", sp->descr, sp->val);
        return;
}


int
mask_is_invalid(uint32_t m)
{
        /*
         * A mask is invalid (will lead to underflow) unless it meets the following condition:
         *  For any given bit, the number of unset bits to the right of it must be greater
         *  than the number of set bits.
         */
        int sum = 0;
        do {
                sum += ( m & 0x1 ) ? 1 : -1;
                m >>= 1;
        } while( m && sum < 0 );
        return sum >= 0;
}

/*
 * generate the next mask with N bits set.  See:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594951/finding-next-bigger-number-with-same-number-of-set-bits
 */
uint32_t
next_mask(uint32_t x)
{
        do {
                uint32_t c = x & -x;
                uint32_t r = x + c;
                x = (((r ^ x) >> 2) / c) | r;
        } while( mask_is_invalid(x));
        return x;
}

/* Given a string of operators (eg "+*-/++"), generate the next permutation */
void
next_perm( char *s )
{
        size_t len = strlen(s);
        assert(strspn( s, "+-*/" ) == len);
        for( int i = 0; i < (int)len; i++) {
                switch(s[i]) {
                case '+': s[i] = '-'; return;
                case '-': s[i] = '*'; return;
                case '*': s[i] = '/'; return;
                case '/': s[i] = '+'; break;
                }
        }
}


int
next_op(struct expression *exp)
{
        int N = exp->count - 1;
        if(strspn( exp->operators, "/" ) == (unsigned)N) {
                exp->mask = next_mask(exp->mask);
                assert( exp->mask >= 1 << 2*N );
        }
        next_perm(exp->operators);
        return exp->mask < 1 << (2*N + 1);
}


/*
 * Initialize exp from the command line arguments.
 */
void
parse_cmd_line(int argc, char **argv, struct expression *exp)
{
        double *v;
        if(argc < 3 || argc > 14) {
                errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Invalid call: must specify between 2 and 14 numeric values");
        }

        argv += 1;
        argc -= 1;
        exp->operands = v = xmalloc( sizeof *v * argc);
        exp->count = argc;

        for( ;*argv; argv++, v++ ) {
                char *end;
                *v = strtod(*argv, &end);
                if(*end != '\0') {
                        errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Invalid input in \"%s\""
                                "at position %ld.  Unexpected value: '%c'",
                                *argv, end - *argv, *end);
                }
        }
        strncpy(exp->operators, "++++++++++++++++++++", exp->count - 1);
        exp->operators[exp->count] = '\0';
        exp->mask = (( 0x1 << ( exp->count - 1 )) - 1);
        exp->mask = next_mask(exp->mask);
        exp->operands = exp->operands;
        exp->stack = xmalloc( exp->count * sizeof *exp->stack);
}


void *
xmalloc(size_t s)
{
        void *r = malloc(s);
        if(r == NULL) {
                err(EXIT_FAILURE, "malloc");
        }
        return r;
}
```

Comment: It's a rough crowd if this hasn't gotten more attention... Couple strange warnings about the use of `snprintf` at line 53 -- `‘%s’` (last) "*directive output may be truncated writing up to 511 bytes into a region of size between 509 and 1020*?" and "*output between 6 and 1028 bytes into a destination of size 1024*". I'll have to figure those out..

Answer (score 1):

I am going to use n instead of 6 to make it a little bit general purpose (adding a note for why below), this will create all possible equations, you will need to create an equation parser which would solve this equations by BODMAS rule.

1. input n from user
2. create array of n numbers => inputs
3. input all elements
4. create array of 2^(2 * n - 1) strings => outputs
5. ```
   for i = 0 to 2^(2 * n - 1) (total combinations)
       outputs[i] = "";   
       for j = 0 to n
           if (i && 2^(j+1) != 0)
               if (i && 2^j != 0)
                   outputs[i] += ("*" + inputs[j])
               else
                   outputs[i] += ("/" + inputs[j])
           else
               if (i && 2^j != 0)
                   outputs[i]  += ("+" + inputs[j])
               else
                   outputs[i]  += ("-" + inputs[j])
   ```

My idea is based on binary representation of a number, your answer would have 2^(2 * n - 1) numbers and binary representation of all numbers from 0 to 2^(2 * n - 1) will be all combinations. 2 bits at 2n and 2n + 1 position represents a sign for number at nth place (00 => -, 01=> +, 10=> / and 11=> *). I can not think of a way to add brackets. You can add a 2^n loop around this to supply all permutations of numbers to input array. I am subtracting 1 in 2^(2 * n - 1) because sign of / and * don't belong at start.

Edit: Another (/better) way I can think of would be using recursion to build all possible combinations as equations and then solve at the end.

Build all possible sub sets in all possible order
something like this (for k = 1 to n) https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-combinations-of-given-length/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution to print and evaluate all combinations of the 4 operators `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` between the numbers. For this code, all operators have the same precedence.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_combination(unsigned mask, int *values, int n) {
    int x = values[0];
    printf("%d", values[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++, mask /= 4) {
        switch (mask % 4) {
        case 0: x += values[i]; printf(" + %d", values[i]); break;
        case 1: x -= values[i]; printf(" - %d", values[i]); break;
        case 2: x *= values[i]; printf(" * %d", values[i]); break;
        case 3: x /= values[i]; printf(" / %d", values[i]); break;
        }
    }
    printf(" = %d\n", x);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = argc - 1;
    int values[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        values[i] = strtol(argv[i + 1], NULL, 0);
    }
    for (unsigned i = 0, mask = 1U << (2 * (n - 1)); i < mask; i++) {
        print_combination(i, values, n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a more elaborated version that handles all permutations of the data set:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_combination(unsigned mask, int *values, int n) {
    int x = values[0];
    printf("%d", values[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++, mask /= 4) {
        switch (mask % 4) {
        case 0: x += values[i]; printf(" + %d", values[i]); break;
        case 1: x -= values[i]; printf(" - %d", values[i]); break;
        case 2: x *= values[i]; printf(" * %d", values[i]); break;
        case 3: x /= values[i]; printf(" / %d", values[i]); break;
        }
    }
    printf(" = %d\n", x);
}

unsigned print_combinations(int *values, int n) {
    unsigned i, mask;
    for (i = 0, mask = 1U << (2 * (n - 1)); i < mask; i++) {
        print_combination(i, values, n);
    }
    return mask;
}

unsigned perm(const int *src, int len, int *dest, int *bits, int n) {
    if (n == len) {
        return print_combinations(dest, len);
    } else {
        unsigned count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (bits[i] == 0) {
                bits[i] = 1;
                dest[n] = src[i];
                count += perm(src, len, dest, bits, n + 1);
                bits[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = argc - 1;
    int values[n], dest[n], bits[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        values[i] = strtol(argv[i + 1], NULL, 0);
        bits[i] = 0;
    }
    printf("%u combinations\n", perm(values, n, dest, bits, 0));
    return 0;
}
```